# How to make typescript recognize that my object assignment is valid?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write this code here:

```js
type A = {
    b: false,
} | {
    b: true,
    p: string;
}

function createA(b: boolean, p: string | undefined): A {

    if (b && p === undefined) {
        throw 'Error';
    }
    const a: A = {
        b,
        p,
    }
    return a;
}
```

But on the creation of `a` I get an error:

> Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Which I understand,`p` is not guaranteed to be defined at this point.

I can obviously fix this by being more explicit with what I'm doing:

```js
function createAFixed(b: boolean, p: string | undefined): A {
    let a: A;
    if (!b) {
        a = { b };
    } else {
        if (p) {
            a = { b, p };
        } else {
            throw 'Error';
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

I was still wondering,is there a "better way" to do this?

Can I use a single conditional and a single assignement to create `a`?

Comment: Your second example also matches the actual type better - `'p' in { p: undefined }` is still `true`, it's not the same as the property not being present at all. You could use overloads to ensure callers pass the right things: https://tsplay.dev/wXgLoW. Alternatively `p: p as string`.

Comment: No, TS cannot infer two objects types from a single object literal, you will need two object literals

Comment: Just to point out `b && p === undefined` will be false if `b` is false or if `p` is a string meaning you could return `{ b: false, p: 'valid string' }` so  I think typescript is right to let you know you might end up returning something that doesn't match the exact type you want.

Comment: @apokryfos I don't think this is why typescript fails the check here, but what you wrote is absolutely correct. The logic I was trying to implement is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator this way

```
function createARefactored(b: boolean, p: string | undefined): A {
  const a: A = b ? { b, p: p as string } : { b }

  if (b && p === undefined) {
    throw 'Error'
  }

  return a
}
```

By using the type assertion `p as string`, you're informing TypeScript that if `b` is `true`, then `p` must be a `string`.

Comment: Wouldn't this cast `p` to `string` even when it's `undefined`?